# How to load custom fonts with the useFonts hook in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-hooks, expo

While waiting for a custom font to load, it's preferable to not render anything until the font is ready.

In the bad old days (December 2021), I learned to use the `<AppLoading />` component in the [`expo-app-loading`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-app-loading/v/2.1.1) package. <sup>1</sup> 
But these days, when I try it, I get a warning saying :

```
expo-app-loading is deprecated in favor of expo-splash-screen:
use SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync() and SplashScreen.hideAsync()
instead. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/
```

[image: warning saying expo-app-loading is deprecated]

I have [a minimalistic project](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q77172403/77172403.zip) that reproduces this warning. <sup>2</sup>

#### *How should I update `App.js` to avoid the warning?*

`App.js` :

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Inter-Black": require("./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.ttf"),
  });
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={[styles.textStyling, styles.textInterBlack]}>
        Inter Black
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyling}>Platform Default</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" },
  textStyling: { fontSize: 30 },
  textInterBlack: { fontFamily: "Inter-Black" },
});
```

### References

- [The NPM `expo-app-loading` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-app-loading/v/2.1.1)
- [The *Fonts - Expo Documentation* as of December 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20211206222110/https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts)
- [A minimalistic project that reproduces the `expo-app-loading` warning](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q77172403/77172403.zip)
- [Installers for Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download)
- [Help on how to install an Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72078381)

---

<sup>1</sup>
The page that used to describe this, is https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts, but it renders 
"404: Not Found" nowadays. [The original page](https://web.archive.org/web/20211206222110/https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-custom-fonts) is still available via the Wayback Machine, though.

<sup>2</sup>
To reproduce: download and unzip into an empty folder of your choice, and change directory (`cd`) into that folder.
Assuming you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download) installed, run `npm install`, `npm start`, and then `a` or `i`, depending on whether the mobile device runs on Android or on iOS. 
Finally, press `r` to reload the application.
(I'm using [an Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72078381).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### *How should I update `App.js` to avoid the warning?*

– In the good new days (September 2023), the modern way is suggested at [the updated *Fonts - Expo Documentation* page](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/user-interface/fonts).

I've [updated the project](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q77172403/77172404.zip) accordingly so that the "deprecated" warning is gone.

[image: The two fonts displayed without any warning]

The updated `App.js` :

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, fontError] = useFonts({
    "Inter-Black": require("./assets/fonts/Inter-Black.ttf"),
  });
  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded || fontError) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded, fontError]);
  if (!fontsLoaded && !fontError) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      <Text style={[styles.textStyling, styles.textInterBlack]}>
        Inter Black
      </Text>
      <Text style={styles.textStyling}>Platform Default</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, paddingTop: 50, alignItems: "center" },
  textStyling: { fontSize: 30 },
  textInterBlack: { fontFamily: "Inter-Black" },
});
```

#### The difference between the two `App.js` versions :

[image: The difference between the two App.js versions]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

### References

- [The *Fonts - Expo Documentation* at the time of writing](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/user-interface/fonts)
- [A minimalistic project that uses the `expo-splash-screen` package](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q77172403/77172404.zip)
- [The NPM `expo-splash-screen` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-splash-screen/v/latest)